# Python: replaced dynamic named parameter in string(for SQL)

Tags: python-3.x

I have a SQL as below:

```
sql= '''
select name from table1 where asof between '$varA' and '$varB'
      union
     select name from table2 where asof between '$varC' and '$varD'
 '''
```

This sql contains dynamic variables.
Use Template.substitude can replace the variables to the value, but in my situation the variable name is dynamic. That is to say I don't know if it's $varA, $varB...
Is there a way i can do dynamic substitude?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
def parseSQL(sql, dict):
    template = Template(sql)
    # print(dict)
    try:
        sql = template.substitute(**dict)
    except KeyError:
        print('Incomplete substitution resulted in KeyError!')
    finally:
        return sql
```

usage:

```
dict = {'startDate': '2021-01-01', 'endDate': '2021-01-31'}
sql = parseSQL(sql, dict)
```

Just use different "dict" to parse the SQL